# Create Product with Woocommerce API and Oauth

Tags: wordpress, api, oauth, woocommerce

I have no problem when I get data. I use this library for client:
https://github.com/bettiolo/oauth-signature-js
for example, to "View List Of Products" I Create this URL with above library (key and others are not real):

```
http://example.com/wc-api/v2/products?oauth_consumer_key=ck_inh2u3n54ui2ny52uh425un4252u5245&oauth_nonce=0.9062660784657346&oauth_signature=jHJGHDhjjh7y3ghGH%gbhfdhHGDS6262&S3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1439148955
```

when I paste this URL in the browser,  I get a list of products.
But **I do not know how I post data**. for example creation of product.

**What is the currect URL for create product?**
please give an example.

Comment: Just out of curiosity.  How are you getting the Customer Keys? are you manually copy past form WP Admin -> User or are you autogenerating it.  I am also looking for similar work.

Comment: when I Enable the REST API in WP Admin -> woocommerce -> setting, woocommerce itself auto generating Customer Key. and I copy it from WP Admin -> User

Comment: Hi, I know how to get the API key.. did you find out how to auto generate it?  so that every time when a user register we done have to manually generate fro the user..

Comment: Hi @DilipRajkumar. sorry, I dont now, but it's good idea

Comment: Please answer your question if you find one. I will also do the same..:)  Happy coding..

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question? I am having the exact same problem.

Comment: @RaymondtheDeveloper
not quite. I was a simple mistake in the GET & POST concept. In creating a product, you should use the POST method. in POST method, DATA will not be sent the by URL. Information will be sent by http Header.
I could not find a way to send information by the http Header. But there is a library based on php that simply does all the work. Unfortunately I don't know php And I don't know how to do it.
Take a look at it, Maybe you understand how to do it.
Notify me either, Thank you!
https://github.com/kloon/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library.git

Comment: I figured it out yesterday. I am using javascript to post my data. My problem was that I had to use JSON.parse or angular.toJson to convert the data so woocommerce can read it. I used Angular with the http service and an oauth script that I found on github, but maybe you can try jquery ajax. Hope it's helpful to you.

Comment: How are you actually generating `oauth_consumer_key` and other parameters required over `http`? please help.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @sasan for creating a product, GET method will not work.  You have to POST data.

Please check this URL http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-a-product

Comment: Hi @Dilip Rajkumar.
As I wrote in the question, I know that I have to "POST" data.
I've reviewed several times this tutorial.
But this tutorial is based on using https, not is http and oauth.

In the url created with standard oauth, we have to send some keys to Authenticate to the server.
To create products must also, at the same url, send product specifications.
**Now what is the standard url for POST data?(data = Oauth Authentication key + product specifications)
how "Oauth Authentication key" and "product specifications" place together?**

Comment: Oops! this is great my friend.

Comment: that link is broken.